# For each row, return the column name of the largest value whilst assigning ties to new groups

Tags: r

I have three variables; and I want to create a new varible showing which column that had the highest number. Data:

```
 x= c(5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1)
 y= c(1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1)
 z= c(1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 1)
 data <-data.frame(x, y, z)
```

Importantly if there are a tie I want this to be indicated too, so that.

1= x is highest

2= y is highest

3= z is highest

4= x and y is highest as tie

5= x and z is highest as a tie

6 = y and z is highest as a tie

7 = x, y and z is all equally high.

I've tried below, but it doesn't handle the ties correctly.

```
 data$Highest <- apply(data, 1, which.max)
 data
```

PS. The correct new variable that I would like to get from the data above should be:

```
 correct= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: I didn't understand how you want to handle ties. You want to assign to the last column with a tie?

Comment: What do you mean by `correct`? Couldn't understand this vector.

Comment: In order to get the column names you could do `apply(data, 1, function(x) names(data)[x == max(x)])`, not sure regarding the structure of your casea thing as you didn't provide it. If it's a list you could do something like  `match(apply(data, 1, function(x) names(data)[x == max(x)]), casea)`

Comment: I've tried to make it clearer by adding the "correct" variable as a PS. That is, this is how I'd like the final new variable to be based on the example data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(plyr)

combn2 <- function(x, y) combn(y, x, paste, collapse="")

x = unlist(sapply(1:ncol(data), combn2, names(data)))

vec = alply(data, 1, function(u) which(paste(names(data)[max(u)==u], collapse='')==x))

#unlist(vec)
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fun <- function(v) {
  stopifnot(length(v) == 3L)
  if (anyNA(v)) stop("NA values in input")
  if (length(unique(v)) == 1L) return(7L)
  rk <- rank(v)
  if (max(rk) %% 1 == 0L) return(which.max(rk))
  test <- rk %% 1 != 0L
  if (sum(test) == 2L) return(sum(which(test)) + 1L)
  stop("undefined case")
}

apply(data, 1, fun)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```